# How to write text to MEDIUMBLOB on mySQL

Tags: mysql

MySql table (part of MediaWiki) stores text in a MEDIUMBLOB (binary) field.
I read it like that:CONVERT(`old_text` USING utf8).
How to write text to this field?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 equivalent ways to convert your text to binary.

1. `BINARY('text')`
2. `CONVERT('text', BINARY)`
3. `CAST('text' AS BINARY)`

Your insert query might look something like:

`INSERT INTO <table> (old_text) VALUES (BINARY('text')) WHERE id = 3;`

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert